# jQuery .get - Specific HTML ID (Not Whole Page)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-get

I am trying to use jQuery ajax to call in a project page.

Assume the xhr variable contains the correct string to the webpage (target page). I have prevented the page as mobile viewport will not load the ajax request.

```
$('a.project__block').on('click', function(e){

    var $el = $(this),
        viewportWidth = $(window).width();

    if (viewportWidth >= 768){
        e.preventDefault();

        var xhr = $.get($(e.currentTarget).data('href'));

        xhr
            .done(open_overlay)
            .fail(function(){
                alert('Could Not Connect, please report to admin!');
            });

    }
});

function open_overlay(data){
    close_overlay_window();
    $('body').addClass('active--overlay').append(data);
    supporting_code();
}

function close_overlay_window(){
    $('#bravedogers').remove();
    $('body').removeClass('active--overlay');
}

function supporting_code(){
    $('.ajax__close__link').on('click', close_overlay_window);
}

function remove__active__classes(){
    // Is the overlay active? If not dont close!
    if (viewportWidth < 768 && $('body').hasClass('active--overlay')){
        close_overlay_window();
    }
}
```

I want to target the specific id which remains constant in all the project pages, e.g:

```
<div id="wrapper__container"></div>
```

At present I am getting this error:

[image]

Ideally can in addition see modernizr being loaded in which causes my page to crash.

Any ideas?

Comment: That's a warning, not an error. Where is it thrown?

Comment: The ajax complete but dumps the whole html page, not the specific div. I am referring to the meta tags the lot. The error is thrown in chrome dev tools

Comment: Let me rephrase. On what line, exactly, is the warning thrown? (Click the link you're provided.)

Comment: it appears to be a google map script being loaded via google apis. It is probably being thrown off due to the scripts being loaded twice.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're trying to do? Append just the wrapper?

```
function open_overlay(data){
    close_overlay_window();
    var container = $(data).find('#wrapper__container');
    $('body').addClass('active--overlay').append(container);
    supporting_code();
}
```

I would see if that makes your warning go away. Just looking at the warning, it looks like Google Maps isn't happy about something.

Comment: sorry no, I am looking to get the a specific id of html code, rather than the entire page. I already have the header and footer and scripts. I only need center content. Similar to a burger, I just want the meat not the bun and tomato :)